# Using typescript from Linux Subsystem

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Windows 10. In the preferences, I can set the typescript sdk.

`// Specifies the folder path containing the tsserver and lib*.d.ts files to use.
"typescript.tsdk": null`

How can I tell Visual Studio Code (installed on Windows 10) to use typescript installed in the subsystem?

Answer (score 1):

you can define the typescript.tsdk setting (File > Preferences > User Settings) pointing to a directory containing the TypeScript tsserver.js file.

For example, my globle typescript is at 
`/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/typescript/`,
then I can set my setting.json lick that:

```
{
   "typescript.tsdk": "/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEotE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzHem.png)

Comment: Run npm in your command line, you can get the your system node_modules path at the last line.